# Recorrer DataGrid

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagrid

Necesito  recorrer un DataGrid para que al momento de seleccionar una fila me muestre los datos de la fila en un reporte. Eh utilizado este codigo:

```html
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                    //for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1;i++)
                {
                    NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("reporte_venta", conexion);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_codigo", Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()));
                    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_codigo", Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value));
                    NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);

                    Reporte rpt = new Reporte();
                    rpt.DataSource = ds;
                    rpt.DataMember = ds.Tables[0].TableName;
                    ReportPrintTool tool = new ReportPrintTool(rpt);
                    tool.ShowRibbonPreviewDialog();
                }
```

Tengo este Codigo Pero al momento de ejecutarlo no me funciona porque al momento de cerrarlo me abre la fila siguiente hasta que recorre todo el datagrid.

**¿Como puedo hacer para que solo me abra el que yo seleccione?**

Comment: si quieres solo los datos de la fila seleccionada, tienes que utilizar RowIndex y no tienes que recorrer todo el datagrid, recorrer la fila entrando por el columnIndex, espero que entiendas un poco la logica de lo que intento decirte.

Answer (score 0):

Lo correcto sería hacer uso de la propiedad RowIndex, aplicado a tu código sería algo así:

```
// Obtenemos el índice de la fila seleccionada
int rowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
// Obtenemos la fila en base a dicho indice
DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex];

NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("reporte_venta", conexion);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_codigo", Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()));

NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);

Reporte rpt = new Reporte();
rpt.DataSource = ds;
rpt.DataMember = ds.Tables[0].TableName;
ReportPrintTool tool = new ReportPrintTool(rpt);
tool.ShowRibbonPreviewDialog();
```